# existe una mejor forma de combinar el codigo html con php que la siguiente?

Tags: php, html

```
<thead>
            <tr>
                <th>nombre</th>
                <th>apellido</th>
                <th>marca</th>
                <th>matricula</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <?php 
            if($blogs){
                foreach($blogs as $blog){
        ?>
            <tr>
                <td><?php echo $blog->nombre; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $blog->apellido; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $blog->marca; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $blog->matricula; ?></td>
                <td>
                    <button>editar</button>
                    <button>eliminar</button>
                </td>
            </tr>
        <?php
                }
            }
        ?>
        </tbody>
```

Comment: No amigo, así se ve en promedio un código de PHP con HTML, es normal.

Comment: **El HTML resultante NO es un HTML válido**. Tendrías que poner los botones en un div fuera de la tabla o añadir un `<th>`al `<thead><tr>`. Esto mejoraría to código.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

lo que podrias hacer para mejorar un poco es cambiar el if por

```
<?php  if(condition): ?>
--aqui va tu codigo html

--opcional--
<?php else: ?>


<?php elseif(condition): ?>
--aqui va mas codigo html


<?php endif ?>
```

tambien lo puedes hacer con el foreach de la misma manera

Answer (score 0):

Puedes obtener el mismo resultado asi:

```
<?php 
    $html = '<thead>
        <tr>
            <th>nombre</th>
            <th>apellido</th>
            <th>marca</th>
            <th>matricula</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>';
    if($blogs){
        foreach($blogs as $blog){        
            $html .= '<tr>
            <td>' . $blog->nombre . '</td>
            <td>' . $blog->apellido . '</td>
            <td>' . $blog->marca . '</td>
            <td>' . $blog->matricula . '</td>
            <td>
                <button>editar</button>
                <button>eliminar</button>
            </td>
        </tr>';        
        }
    }        
    $html .= '</tbody>';
    echo $html;
```

Este metodo es muy efectivo cuando tienes que intermezclar los dos muchas veces, ya que te ahorra estar abriendo y cerrando el tag de php multiples veces.

Comment: Creo estas repitiendo el fragmento de encabezado por cada elemento de tu colección.